# Xamarin.Firebase.Database Compatibility Issue

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin Andoid project (Not a Xamarin Forms project) using Visual Studio 2019 and it is working fine (No any code changes done). By default it has these Nuget packages installed:

[image]

I tried to install **Xamarin.Firebase.Database** latest version (71.1601.0) and got this error.

[image]

Then I tried to install the previous version (60.1142.1) and it got installed. But When I try to build the project I got this error.

[image]

I am unable to run the project so how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you just install the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.3, you still cannot install `Xamarin.Firebase.Database (71.1601.0)`, you should install following nuget packages.

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 28.0.0.3) 

Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI (= 28.0.0.3) 

Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment (= 28.0.0.3) 

Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 28.0.0.3) 

 Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable (= 28.0.0.3)
```

I installed `Xamarin.Firebase.Database latest version (71.1601.0)` successfully, Here is my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @A.M.Roomi
Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

i got same error a week ago. Remove adroid native nuget packages all from your adroid part. Then install your package. if you need, then install your android packages.

I had one packages installed named "android.support.*****". Searched but couldnt find solution easily. Compiler suggests that installing so many packages. I removed the one android package then i could installed the xamarin packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and solved it as follows. My error was an Xamarin.Firebase.Common (71.1610.0) installation error. Error disappeared after installing Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 "(28.0.0.3). Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Xamarin.Essentials has a dependency on Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.3 while Xamarin.Firebase.Database has a dependency on Xamarin.Android.Support v4 28.0.0.1. The error message is telling you to directly add a reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.3. That should fix the problem for you.